# What forms first: the dark matter halo or the galaxy?

Tags: dark-matter, galaxies

I read that in the early Universe dark matter forms halos, and dust and gas inside those halos formed the first ever galaxies. I am curious to know whether the dust and gas formed the galaxy inside a previously formed halo, or whether the halo formed around the dust and gas.

Comment: Note that you have accepted an answer that consists of non-mainstream claims that don't even really answer your question. Please consider unaccepting it.

Comment: @ACuriousMind What answer are you referring to?

Comment: Ah, you had accepted a wrong answer that has since been deleted for reasons unrelated to its content. Never mind.

Answer (score 2):

In the 'standard' model of galaxy formation in a $\Lambda$CDM cosmology (which admittedly has it's fair share of glitches), the halo forms first. This is because in the early Universe, most of the energy density is in the form of radiation (most of the energy is in the form of photons). The gas that will eventually form stars and galaxies is still so hot that it is a plasma, i.e. made of charged particles, which interact strongly with the photons. The result is that any bit of gas that tries to cool and collapse is immediately re-heated by the bath of photons. In the meantime, the dark matter, which feels no such radiation pressure, begins to collapse and form halos. Eventually the Universe expands and cools enough that electrons can bind to protons and make (neutral) hydrogen, which is transparent to the photons and can finally begin to cool and collapse into the now (partially) formed dark matter halos.

You mention dust, but until the first stars have had time to do some fusion reactions, there is nothing in the Universe to make dust out of: there is only H, He, and trace amounts of Li.

Comment: But are the dark matter objects before galaxies formed in the shape of halos? Seems to me like the halos themselves are because the galaxy or does dark matter naturally collect into a halo shape?

Comment: A dark matter halo really isn't donut-shaped, which you seem to think it is.

Comment: @C.A.C. as Peter Shor points out, DM halos are thought to be approximately spherical, with a central concentration (dense in the middle).

Comment: That makes sense. I always wondered why dark matter wouldn't be shaped like a sphere.

Comment: Thanks for your answer it's helped me considerably. You say the Cold Dark Matter model has it's fair share of glitches,I am curious if there's any specific fault in the theory that other theories might better explain?

Comment: @xavier rae there are specific points which other theories address better because they are specifically made to address exactly those points, but overall LCDM theory is still the best we've got. The possible exception is 'Warm Dark Matter', which is sort of on par at the moment, loosely speaking.